# How to use remove_if with the ! of a function (the not of a function)

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

Basically, I am trying to do this:

word.resize(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), not1(isalpha())) - word.begin());

I know about the ugly work-around where you just declare your own function and pass it. But is there a way to get this working? I get the message "too few arguments in function call" with a red line under the isalpha function.

Comment: you might want to add an example of what you are trying to accomplish because I don't understand what your question is asking.

Comment: Are you looking for http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/not1/ ?

Comment: paring resize with remove works, but typically you should use erase `word.erase(remove_if(...));` because it's more general and doesn't require the extra `- word.begin()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++03, you'd normally use something like:

```
std::not1(std::ptr_fun(isalpha))
```

In C++11, you'd more often use a lambda:

```
word.resize(
   remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), 
             [](char ch){return !isalpha(ch);}) -word.begin());
```

Edit: You might also want to read a [similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11203/most-efficient-way-in-c-to-strip-strings) that was asked on Code Review just yesterday. It's not quite identical, but similar enough that it's likely to be of interest (it's not asking about `!isalpha`, but about removing non-alphabetic characters from a string).

Edit2: Doing a quick test, this seems to work:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ctype.h>

template <class T>
T gen_random(size_t len) {
    T x;
    x.reserve(len);

    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(x), len, rand);
    return x;
}

template <class Container>
void test2(Container &input) {
    input.resize(
        std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
        [](char ch){return !isalpha(ch);}) -input.begin());
}

int main(){

    std::string input(gen_random<std::string>(100));
    std::cout << "Input: \n" << input << "\n\n";

    input.resize(
        std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
        [](char ch){return !isalpha(ch);}) -input.begin());

    std::cout << "Result: " << input << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

At least when I run this, I get:

```
Input:
ë♠╖G▐│↕M╚C╗ïª▼♥Z}       8%▼]╘╦ⁿû⌡E;‼
∟█«2 ÜPε@x6²↕I2÷₧}I▄¡O¶≥D@f╨k─0╖2;í"÷"æ¥

Result: lRIGMCZEPxIIODfk
```

From the looks of things, the random input I generated included at least one carriage return, so the first few characters in the input aren't visible in the output. I checked a couple starting from the "G" and then a couple at the end, and all seemed well though.

Comment: I tested the code out, but this line of code makes my word become "". The word was "Produced". Here is the code I used:

word.resize(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char letter){return !isalpha(letter);}) - word.end());

Do you see any obvious problems?

Comment: In this case using a function adaptor is probably preferable to a lambda. No need to force everything into a lambda just because we have them.

Comment: @user904963 Yes there's a problem with that. you have `- end()` there so that the return value will always be 0 or negative. you should use `erase` instead of `remove` exactly to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: @user904963 `word.erase(remove_if(begin(word),end(word),not1(std::ptr_fun(isalpha))));`

Comment: @user904963: Yup. I should add that I mostly agree with bames53 though -- for this, `erase` probably makes more sense than `resize`.